# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect leaking memory in ARC

Tags: memory-management, ios7, exc-bad-access, cgimageref

I'm calling

```
CGImageRef tmp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.originalImage CGImage], newSize);
```

a ton of times and the app is eventually crashing but I don't retain a reference to the image.  Shouldn't tmp get garbage collected?

The error is an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` uses a rect as a second param, why you pass a `newSize` to it? Seems it's a size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in ARC, this function doesn't clean up after itself.

After you call it, use this:

```
CGImageRelease(tmp);
tmp = NULL;
```

Comment: In fact, nothing in `CoreFoundation` (including `CoreGraphics` and stuff) is automatically reference counted by ARC. A little bit of nitpicking: It should be `tmp = NULL;` not `tmp = nil;`. `nil` is for Objective C pointers.

Comment: And not releasing memory is bad but will not cause his `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problem.

Comment: It will if I run out of memory :)